# Four functions problem

Tags: mathematical-programming, mathematical-analysis, primes

**This is not from online contest**

Hi guys, a friend of mine recently give me this problem that I couldn't figure out an effective way to solve it.

---

### Four functions

You are given four functions
$$
\begin{align}
A(x)&=\text{Number of }i\text{ where }1\leq i\leq x\text{ and }\gcd(i,x)=1\\
B(x)&=\sum_{d|x}A(d)\\
C(x)&=\text{Sum of exponents of each prime in the prime factorization of }B(x)\\
D(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^{x}C(x)
\end{align}
$$

**Input:**

- First line: $T$ [number of test cases]
- Each test case consists of an integer $N$

**Output format**

For each test case, print a single integer denoting the value of $D(N)$ in a new line.

**Input constraints**

$$\begin{align}1\leq T\leq 10^6\\1\leq N\leq 10^6\end{align}$$

---

Here's my observation:

- About the constraints, there are 10^6 test cases, each test case can be as large as 10^6, I estimate we need an algorithm that is at least O(nlogn). Otherwise we will have TLE.
- I guess this problem is a **math** one. We somehow need to come up with an efficient formula to resolve all 4 functions.
- I know for sure if we solve this problem naively, we cannot pass all test cases. Even if we use the best method to compute `gcd` and `prime factor`.
- I've thought about this one for two days I can't find an acceptable solution for this problem. You can assume that this problem have time limit of 5 seconds.

Since this is a **math** problem, some talented and gifted genius out there might be interested. :D

Please help to come up with a formula to solve this, or provide an understandable solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you had a table containing the largest prime factor of x, for 1 ≤ x ≤ 1,000,000, how long would factoring any number up to 1,000,000 take?

Comment: Nobody asked you to calculate any gcd. How can you calculate A(x) without calculating any gcd?

Comment: Given the factorisation of x, how do you find the factorisation of all divisors of x, without even calculating any divisors?

Comment: You're sure it's not from an online contest? Or an offline contest? Or any other context where you should find the solution yourself?

Comment: @gnasher729, yes, this is an interview question. My friend couldn't find the solution, so he ask me if I can.

Comment: @gnasher729 it happened in the past so I think it's ok to have a public soluton here. Anyway only I and my friend know if someone can solve it.

Comment: @gnasher729, your first question, I think it is square root of N

Comment: @gnasher729, from what I understand for the first function. It ask us to count the number for i from 1 to x, such that gcd(i,x) is 1

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't know the solution for your 3rd question

Comment: The function $A$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). The function $B$ it is a [known property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737422/euler-totient-function-sum-of-divisors-theorem-2-2-apostol) that it is equal to $B(x)=x$.

Comment: @gnasher729 it seems that you're guiding me to a solution that is an algorithm to efficiently compute the result, rather than a formula for the problem.

Comment: thanks @plop, any more hint :D I'm weak at prime-related problems.

Comment: @LocTruong Yes. I don't have an algorithm, but I know I would find one easily by following these steps. And having an algorithm isn't helpful if you can't create it yourself. Your first comment: Say I give you the number 1001 to factor. You look up in the table that the largest divisor of 1001 is 13. What would be your next steps? There are only three steps to get the complete factorisation of 1001.

Comment: @gnasher729 my first thought is to loop from 13 to 2 to factorize 1001

Comment: The next simplification that I see is that $D(x)=B(x!)$. Now, suppose $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ are the primes less than or equal to $x$. We have that $B(x!)=\sum_{i=1}^k \nu_{p_i}(x!)$, where $\nu_{p_i}(x!)$ is the exponent of the prime $p_i$ in the factorization of $x!$. This number you can compute using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula). So, an algorithm could be to generate all primes up to $x$ and then apply Legendre's formula for each of them and sum the results.

Comment: In the comment above I meant $C$ instead of $B$.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: This looks identical to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62777612/781723, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245127/65105, which claims it is from an online contest.  Where did you encounter it?

Comment: @D.W. like I said, this is from a friend of mine. One more point, because you have mentioned that this **was** from an online contest, it will not likely come from another online contest.

Comment: "I guess this problem is a math one." -- so why do you post it here and not on [math.SE]? Not to say that we don't have competent people here, but you'll certainly have access to more number theory experts over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put together the two comments.

The function $A$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), which is often called $\phi$.

The function $B(x)=\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$ is [known to be equal to](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737422) $B(x)=x$.

Now, observe that $D(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{x}C(B(i))=\sum_{i=1}^{x}C(i)=C(x!)$, where the last equation is because $C$ satisfies $C(a)+C(b)=C(ab)$.

Now, if $p_1<p_2<\ldots<p_k$ are the primes less than or equal to $x$ and $x!=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dotsm p_k^{a_k}$, then $$C(x!)=a_1+a_2+...+a_k$$

We can use [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to compute each $a_i$. Note that the formula doesn't need to compute $x!$, but it computes $$a_i=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p_i}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p_i^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{p_i^3}\right\rfloor+\ldots$$
where there are actually finitely many summands.

So, an algorithm to compute $D(x)$ can be:

1. Compute the primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ up to $x$. This can be done using some sieve, like [Erathostenes'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or [Atkin's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin)
2. Then for each prime evaluate Legendre's formula above, which takes about $\log_{p_i}(x)$ divisions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try implementing the solution base on your algorithm. It's interesting to know the equivalent of each function and also to know that they're easy to compute.